# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to solve problem set

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, coredump

I'm trying to solve the Caesar pset in the Harvard CS50 course, and I think I'm mostly on the right way, but I just started getting the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Im still super new to coding, which is why i was having a bit of trouble figuring out the problem, when I was looking at other similar questions. Maybe someone could have a glance at my code and help.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char rotate(char c, int n);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // SAVE CLA AS VARIABLES
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);
    string cipher = "";
    int length  = strlen(plaintext);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        cipher[i] = rotate(plaintext[i], key);
    }

    printf("%s\n", cipher);
}

char rotate(char c, int n)
{
    //test if c = key is in right range
    c = c + n;

    while (c > 122)
    {
        c = c - 122 + 64;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: First step should always be to run your program in a debugger. It will show you where that segmentation fault happened. And you can inspect variable and look for unexpected values.

Comment: Good tip! I am having some trouble setting up the debugger in the CS50 codespace environment, but its probably a good investment of time to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to remember that `string` is an alias for `char *`. That is, `string` is a *pointer* to a `char`.

Then for the problem: The definition

```
string cipher = "";
```

makes the variable `cipher` point to an empty string literal. More specifically it makes `cipher` point to the first element of an array, s all literal strings are really arrays of character. It's an array of only a single element, which is the string terminator character `'\0'`.

Like any other array, its size is fixed and can not be made larger.

Unlike other arrays, literal string arrays are not allowed to be modified.

So you have two errors in your code:

1. You attempt to write out of bounds of an array;
2. And you attempt to modify a read-only literal string

Both of these errors leads to *undefined behavior*, which is a common cause of crashes.

Comment: I declared the variable cipher as equal to plaintext, so the array of characters is as long as the array of the plaintext variable, and my loop works in filling out the array. Thanks!

Comment: @rasmusschaal I hope you added one character to fit the string null-terminator. And actually added the terminator.

Comment: Do I have to add \0 to the string manually? I thought it was added automatically to separate different strings in the memory?

Comment: @rasmusschaal No it will not be added automatically.